# (PHP) How to display data from 2 different tables in the database to a bootstrap table

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

I'm a beginner in PHP. I'm currently developing a website where **I want to display in the bootstrap `table` the data that will come from 2 different tables in the MySQL** database. The two tables are ***client*** and ***useraccounts***. I want to display their data in a single row. Here is what I have right now: [(Please Click to see the image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/St9AF.png) As you can see on the photo, my problem is **I can only display the data from the *client* table but not from the *useraccounts* table**. The blank cells in the bootstrap table should be the data coming from the *useraccounts* table but I failed to display it.

---

Here is my table for ***client*** and ***useraccounts:*** [(tables) Please click the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1kdI.png)

Your help will be highly appreciated. Here is my **code:**

```
<?php
echo "<table style='cursor: pointer;' class='table table-hover table-striped 
table-bordered table-responsive ' >";
echo "<tr>
    <th>Company Name</th>
    <th>Contact Person</th>
    <th>Client Address</th>
    <th>Contact no.</th>    
    <th>E-mail</th>
    <th>User Birthdate</th>
    <th>User Mobile no.</th>
    <th>Username</th>
    <th>User Fistname</th>
    <th>User Lastname</th>
    <th>User Birthdate</th>
  </tr>";

class TableRows extends RecursiveIteratorIterator { 
  function __construct($it) { 
    parent::__construct($it, self::LEAVES_ONLY); 
    }

  function current() {
    return "<td>" . parent::current(). "</td>";
    }

  function beginChildren() { 
    echo "<tr class='table table-hover'>"; 
    } 

  function endChildren() { 
    echo "</tr>" . "\n";
   } 
} 

$servername = "mysql5013.hostbuddy.com";
$username = "*****_crb";
$password = "*****";
$dbname = "db_*****_crb";

try { 
//data from client table
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, 
$password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT cli_company_name, cli_contact_person, 
       cli_address, cli_contactno, cli_email FROM client WHERE status=1 "); 
$stmt->execute();

// set the resulting array to associative
$result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

//data from useraccounts table
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$stmt2 = $conn->prepare("SELECT username, user_fname, user_lname, user_bdate 
           FROM useraccounts WHERE status=1 AND 
company_name='".$result['cli_company_name']."' "); 
$stmt2->execute();

// set the resulting array to associative
$result2 = $stmt2->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

foreach(new TableRows(new RecursiveArrayIterator($stmt->fetchAll())) as 
$k=>$v) { 
    echo $v;
}

 foreach(new TableRows(new RecursiveArrayIterator($stmt2->fetchAll())) as 
$l=>$w) { 
    echo $w;
}
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: Sounds like a job for.... [JOIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html)s.

Comment: Is there any mapping column between `user` and `client` tables?

Comment: @DarshanMehta I already update it, there the tables of my database

Comment: @ErickaLeonardoGregorio how do you figure out which client belongs to which result in the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table structure shared in the question do not show a relationship between the 2 tables. You can use a `JOIN` query to fetch the data from the 2 tables however you will need to have a relation between the tables in order to join them. Below is the query that can be used.

```
select  c.cli_company_name, 
        c.cli_contact_person, 
        c.cli_address, 
        c.cli_contact_no, 
        c.cli_email,
        ua.user_bdate,
        ua.user_mobilenum, 
        ua.username, 
        ua.user_fname, 
        ua.user_lname 
from    client c
join    useraccounts ua
on      c.<some field> = ua.<matching field>
where   ....
```

In this query, the `<some field>` and `<matching field>` specify the relation (it could be PK of one table as FK in the other table) that will help in joining the tables. Additionally you can also append a `WHERE` clause to filter the data if required.

Though this would not provide a complete answer to your question, it should help you in providing appropriate guidance to move ahead.